# How to implement Push Notification in Hybrid Mobile Application using Bluemix

Tags: mobile, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I was earlier implementing push in my hybrid mobile application using the below code.

```
function EnablePushNotification(email)
{   

    var config = {

            applicationId:'',
            applicationRoute:'',
            applicationSecret:''
            //applicationSecret:''

    };
    console.log("EnablePushNotification : " + email);
    return IBMBluemix.initialize(config)
    .then(function() {
            return IBMPush.initializeService();
    })
    .then(function(push1) {
        var push = IBMPush.getService();
        //device.model
        //userName
        push.registerDevice(email, email, "alertNotification")
            .done(function(response) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Device Registered : " + response);  
                console.log("Device Registered : " + response);
                push.subscribeTag("SmarterSAM-Test").done(function(response) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Device Subscribed : " + response);
                console.log("Device Subscribed : " + response); 
            }, function(err){
                navigator.notification.alert("Error in subscribe : " + err);
                console.log("Error in subscribe : " + err); 
            });
        }, function(err){
            navigator.notification.alert("Error in Registering Device : " + err);
            //console.log("Error in subscribe : " + err);
        });
   });

}

function alertNotification(message)
{
    IBMBluemix.getLogger().info("Received notification");
    navigator.notification.alert("Received notification : " + message);
}
```

Now due to change in Push service, i am implementing the Push Notification, \

```
function EnablePushNotification(email)
{
    //deviceUserID = email;
    console.log("--Inside EnablePushNotification--");



    try {
        //initialize SDK with IBM Bluemix application ID and route
        //TODO: Please replace <APPLICATION_ROUTE> with a valid ApplicationRoute and <APPLICATION_ID> with a valid ApplicationId        
        debugger;
        BMSClient.initialize("<APPLICATION_ROUTE>","<APPLICATION_ID>");



        var success = function(message) { console.log("Success: " + message); };
        var failure = function(message) { console.log("Error: " + message); };
        MFPPush.registerDevice({}, success, failure);

        this.registerNotificationsCallback();
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException) {
        console.log("Error in initilization-->>" + MalformedURLException);        
    }


}
```

But i am getting the below ERROR.

Error in initilization-->>ReferenceError: BMSClient is not defined.

In my index.html, i have included MPUSH.js and BMSClient.js

i got these .js  (MFPush.js,BMSClient.js) files by creating a cordova project and adding environment to them.

I have gone through the blumix docs, Push Notification is given for iOS , Android and Cordova applications but not for hybrid mobile app.

Please help in this regard !!

I am not using adapters in my hybrid application to initialize the Bluemix SDK.

I also checked the below link.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/242476/bluemix-push-service-error-while-registering-devic.html

Comment: What version of Mobile First Platform Foundation are you using?

Comment: Hi Dave ! I am using MFP version 7.1

Answer (score 0):

**Final Update**

I originally thought that the project was having trouble picking up the cordova bridge, however, I figured out that the native dependencies are missing. This is due to MFP not supporting Gradle, so you will need to make some edits to the plugins to get the project working in MFP.

Complete the following for each plugin you desire to use:

- Download the appropriate `.aar` from the [list of Bluemix MobileFirst maven central repos](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|mobilefirstplatform).
- Extract the `classes.jar` from the `.aar` and rename the `.jar` to something identifiable to that plugin (i.e. core-1.1.1.jar)
- After adding the plugin to your project, create a `libs` folder at `plugins/<plugin-name>/src/android` and drop your newly renamed `.jar` into that `libs` directory.
- Lastly, open the `plugin.xml` file and add the build path to the `.jar` within the `<platform name="android">` target. It should look something like this `<lib-file src="src/android/libs/core-1.1.1.jar" />`

You will need to do this for each Bluemix Mobile Services plugin that you add until MFP supports Gradle.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the reply, i tried to implement as suggested by you but still i am getting the same below ERROR.

Error in initilization-->>ReferenceError: BMSClient is not defined.                                              i have a query here , do i need to add these   files CDVMFPPush.java and CDVBMSClient.java  in libs folder or android src folder.

Comment: Android src folder is probably more appropriate. I'm treating them as jars in my instructions (based on old docs), so i think you're right.

I you get it working let me know. I will have some time to try this out for myself next week.

Comment: Hi Dave, I am unable to figure out the problem. So i am sharing the link for the code. Please check and advise after seeing my sample project code for the push notification. ( I have created a Mobile First Project and implemented a push notification). Here is the link for the same.                           https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuSOc4RrrpJengwUFVKQ1RsLWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: apologies for the wait @user3719130 we are still investigating and plan to have a resolution for you next week

Comment: @user3719130 I was able to re-create your issues and am struggling to find a solution, I hope to have some more concrete advice after discussing these issues with our developers.

Comment: @user3719130 see the final update above, we finally found a workaround for your issue. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi Dave !! Big Thanks for your final update. Need one favour, can you please share my sample project code for the push notification which i shared with you via google drive with the final update changes, so that i can have a look at the final code which is working on your machine. In the meantime implementing the solution given in the final update above.     In this way i will be able to cross-check the sol provided by you.

Comment: @user3719130 Please follow my instructions and let me know if you have problems. I legally cannot add the .jar and deliver it to you

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the solution, I tried to follow the steps and implement it but i am getting the same error, i am sharing the link for the code. Please have a look at the code and advise. Here is the link for the code.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzuSOc4RrrpJaDNfQkJrOUhsQjg

Comment: @user3719130 I cannot access the link you provided, I urge you to follow my instructions again to ensure you are doing them correctly

Comment: My Apologies Dave, here is the link, i am sure you can access it now. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuSOc4RrrpJaWFTZlgxdFNZWU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3719130 It seems you have used the same core-1.1.1.jar in both plugins. Make sure you pull down the push .aar and add that classes.jar to the push plugin.