# Push notification using IBM Worklight and IBM Bluemix

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

For the last few days, I have been wanting to implement a push notification in my IBM Worklight project using the cloud service IBM Bluemix. I didn't get any good resource/sample based on my requirement.

Please help me to find a solution for a push notification in IBM Worklight mobile app using IBM Bluemix service. I have tried the following references:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-push-app/index.html

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush

Answer (score 1):

The Bluemix push notifications implementation is not compatible with Worklight apps. If you'd like to use push notifications in your Worklight application, use the push API as provided by Worklight: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to be a rebel and attempt to get a hybrid app working in Worklight with IBM Push Notifications on Bluemix you could try following the steps I have outlined in [this answer to "How to implement Push Notification in Hybrid Mobile Application using Bluemix"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684834/4266547)

However, due to some of the restrictions Idan mentions, you will only be able to get Android working. We currently do not have any work around for iOS.

Also, check out these articles, published today, for more accurate and up to date tutorial (native ios and android)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-mobile-application-security-bluemix-mobile-services-1-trs/index.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-mobile-application-security-bluemix-mobile-services-2-trs/index.html